# Import data from a single column of CSV file in Google Apps Script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script to import data from a CSV file where the datas are in a single column. I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial?hl=en#section-2-importing-data-from-a-csv-file) to read datas from CSV file but since the datas are in single column, comma delimiter is not working and the code is hanging whenever I run the function.

Here is my code:

```
function importCSV(getfile) {
    getfile = "Copy of FR1_1.csv";
    var getFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fId);
    var fi = getFolder.getFilesByName(getfile);

    if (fi.hasNext()) { 
        var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var newSheet = ssNew.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        var file = fi.next();
        var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
        var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
        // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into the sheet
        for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
            newSheet.getRange(newSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i][0]));
        }
        Browser.msgBox("CSV imported successfully!");
    }
}

function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to COMMA.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
        (
            // Delimiters.
            "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

            // Quoted fields.
            "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

            // Standard fields.
            "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
        ),
        "gi"
    );

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [
        []
    ];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec(strData)) {

        // Get the delimiter that was found.
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[1];

        // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
        // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
        // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
        // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
        if (
            strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
            (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
        ) {

            // Since we have reached a new row of data,
            // add an empty row to our data array.
            arrData.push([]);

        }

        // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
        // let's check to see which kind of value we
        // captured (quoted or unquoted).
        if (arrMatches[2]) {

            // We found a quoted value. When we capture
            // this value, unescape any double quotes.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[2].replace(
                new RegExp("\"\"", "g"),
                "\""
            );

        } else {

            // We found a non-quoted value.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[3];

        }

        // Now that we have our value string, let's add
        // it to the data array.
        arrData[arrData.length - 1].push(strMatchedValue);
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return (arrData);
}
```

How can I import datas from a single column of CSV file in spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you share your csv file?

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this code for single column and it works fine.

```
   function importCSV() {
    var getfile = "singleColumn.csv";
    var getFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fId);
    var fi = getFolder.getFilesByName(getfile);
    if (fi.hasNext()) { 
        var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var newSheet = ssNew.getSheetByName("csv");
        var file = fi.next();
        var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
        var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
        // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into the sheet
        for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
         newSheet.appendRow(csvData[i]);
            //newSheet.getRange(newSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, csvData.length,1).setValue(csvData[i][0]);
        }
        Browser.msgBox("CSV imported successfully!");
     }
   }
```

You may [read more from this article](https://googleappsscriptdeveloper.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/import-data-from-csv-to-google-spreadsheet/).